# How to run cmd command in visual c++ witjout console

Tags: windows, forms, visual-c++

I am trying to build a visual c++ form application that run cmd command on a button click without console window for example on button1 click run ipconfig with any other command with an aurgument

Comment: You probably have to redirect standard input and standard output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i dont know how to do that i am having problem with creating process

Comment: Use an object of the System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo class with System.Diagnostics.Process.Start. Set UseShellExecute to false, RedirectStandardInput to true and RedirectStandardOutput to true. After that you can use the System.IO.StreamWriter Process.StandardInput to write to the input and System.IO.Stream.StreamReader Process.StandardOutput to read the output.